# Excel - COUNTIFS on 1 range using 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2010, countif

I've got a spreadsheet full of enquiries we have got over the years as a business. I'd like to have a summary table that can tell me how many of those enquiries were priced per year.

I've put together a small table to illustrate.

[image]

Under the enquiries (B) column, I have this formula to tell me how many came through that year:
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(YEAR($C$9:$C$108)=A3))

Under the priced (C) column, I'd like a COUNTIFS formula to count how many of those enquiries were priced.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the `COUNTIFS` formula you tried?

Comment: why not use a pivot table?  Seems that this is a perfect use case for one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, for example in cell `G2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(YEAR(C2:C20)=E2), N(B2:B20<>""))
```

**Note**: I am assuming from your question that priced means it has a value associated.

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Where in `F2` cell we have:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(YEAR(C2:C20)=E2))
```

or you can have all at once with O365:

```
=LET(years, YEAR(C2:C20), yearsUx, UNIQUE(years), values, B2:B20, 
 enquires, BYROW(yearsUx, LAMBDA(y, SUMPRODUCT(N(years = y)))),
 priced, BYROW(yearsUx, LAMBDA(y, SUMPRODUCT(N(years = y), N(values <>"")))),
 VSTACK({"Year", "Enquires", "Priced"}, HSTACK(yearsUx, enquires, priced))
)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file all at once]

Comment: Thanks David. Your first solution solved the issue straight away. Thanks again.